# Sum up parameters for only most recent date in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have data that I'm aggregating based on various criteria, but there are multiple date records for each ID code. I cannot figure out how to tell Access to only SUM if the date is the most recent date.

So for a given IDcode (`API number`), the query is SUM-ing all data that meets the listed criteria, for all dates. 
I want to limit it to just look at the most recent date - but every record has a different most recent date (`JobEndDate`).
 Any ideas? I'm relatively new to Access/SQL.

```
SELECT 
    dbo_RegistryUpload.APINumber,
    Sum(dbo_RegistryUploadIngredients.PercentHFJob) AS 4070, 
    Max(dbo_RegistryUpload.JobEndDate) AS MaxOfJobEndDate
FROM 
    (dbo_RegistryUpload INNER JOIN dbo_RegistryUploadPurpose 
    ON dbo_RegistryUpload.pKey = dbo_RegistryUploadPurpose.pKeyRegistryUpload) 
    INNER JOIN dbo_RegistryUploadIngredients 
    ON dbo_RegistryUploadPurpose.pKey = dbo_RegistryUploadIngredients.pKeyPurpose
WHERE (((dbo_RegistryUploadPurpose.TradeName) Like "*40/70*")) 
    OR (((dbo_RegistryUploadPurpose.TradeName) Like "*40-70*"))
GROUP BY dbo_RegistryUpload.APINumber
HAVING (((dbo_RegistryUpload.APINumber) Like "42*")) 
    OR (((dbo_RegistryUpload.APINumber) Like "42*"));
```

Here is my data (already summed by date)

```
APINumber        4070         JobEndDate
42003045490000   39.30987804   18-Feb-15
42003045490000   7.56203693    24-Feb-15
42003046050000   6.334731543   05-Jun-15
42003317940000   1.624367441   24-Nov-14
42003317940000   2.359888624   25-Nov-14
42003318510000   4.644843464   22-Jul-13
42003322540000   2.476440141   04-Dec-14
```

My desired output would be the following

```
APINumber        4070         JobEndDate
42003045490000   7.56203693    24-Feb-15
42003046050000   6.334731543   05-Jun-15
42003317940000   2.359888624   25-Nov-14
42003318510000   4.644843464   22-Jul-13
42003322540000   2.476440141   04-Dec-14
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected output. I have an idea of what you want to do, but it would help to see the data.

Comment: Edited to include data and output!

Comment: From the data shown it would seem you just need to select the max 'JobEndDate' for each 'APINumber'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid trying to do everything in one query.

Create a new query to select the `MAX JobEndDate` from your source data for each `APINumber`.

Join this to your existing query (on`JobEndDate` and `APINumber`) to list only the rows with the latest `JobEndDate`.